# doAfterCompose is not invoked for GenericForwardComposer

Tags: zk

I'm upgrading ZK project from ZK 3.6.4 to 7.0.3. The main page uses the composer that extends GenericForwardComposer:

```
<window id="main" width="100%" height="100%" apply="myproject.web.MainLayoutComposer">
```

However, I see that `doAfterCompose` method in `MainLayoutComposer` is not invoked at all which leads to application crash. Could you please help me to find out why this method is not called? If I upgrade to 5.0.12 the same problem occurs. Did I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

You may check whether you override a right method?
Since ZK 5, it added a Generic Types support for all composer classes.